# Removing <body> with a userscript

Tags: html, regex, innerhtml, document-body

I'm sorry, but I am not very good with programming. I am trying to fix this irritating bug on my school's website through a userscript. I have tested the RegEx on several pages, at least that works. I need to make the userscript remove the parts I don't want to see. This is a snippet from the source of the website, I have marked what needs to be removed with '//'.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
//<html><head>
//<title>404 Not Found</title>
//</head><body>
//<h1>Not Found</h1>
//<p>The requested URL /get.php was not found on this server.</p>
//</body></html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

This is my userscript that does not work. I know it reflects my skills as a programmer, please don't hate.

```
var REGEX = /<HTML>(.*?)([^\n]*?\n+?)+?<\/BODY><\/HTML>/ig;
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(REGEX, '');
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove this? How is it being generated?

Comment: It would help if you could explain what "doesn't work" in more detail, but I'm going to assume that you get an empty page after the script is run - the `g` flag of your regex will cause it to remove __all__ the HTML.

Comment: @Rawing The `g` flag won’t cause that. The second `<html>` tag has attributes which don’t match `<HTML>`. This isn’t the problem.

Comment: Xufox, you get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This markup is obviously invalid, but the browser (at least Chrome and Firefox) will merge these two `<html>` sections together with its best guess. So interacting with `document.body` is probably not what you want.

Doing something like this will visually fix the issue:

```
document.querySelector('h1').remove() // remove first h1 "Not Found"
document.querySelector('p').remove() // remove first p "The requested..."
```

Comment: I will try that right away, thank you. My only worry is the problem is actually repeated later in the document, so I have two instances of it. But this is still a huge help.

Comment: It worked! It removed both instances, as there wasn't any actual <body>-content in between them, so I just ran it twice.